# How to find nearest location when using reverseGeocodeLocation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reverse-geocoding, clplacemark

I am working with reverseGeocodeLocation and sometime with a given latitude and longitude a 'subThoroughfare' and 'thoroughfare' are not returned. If there a way to get the closest 'subThoroughfare' and 'thoroughfare' to that location?

Here is my code so far:

```
var nearAddressString = ""

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userCLLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)

            } else {

                if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                    let subThroughfare = p.subThoroughfare ?? ""

                    let thoroughfare = p.thoroughfare ?? ""

                    let subLocality = p.subLocality ?? ""

                    let subAdministrativeArea = p.subAdministrativeArea ?? ""

                    let postalCode = p.postalCode ?? ""

                    nearAddressString = "\(subThroughfare) \(thoroughfare) \n \(subLocality) \n \(subAdministrativeArea) \n \(postalCode)"

                    print(nearAddressString)

                } else {
                    print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
                }

            }

        })
```

Comment: Did you check if your placemarks array maybe contains more than one result ?

Comment: I just checked and it only contains 1 result. What I tried to was slightly change the latitude and longitude until I get a result, but I know this isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: Try checking the addressDictionary property on CLPlacemark then. I did not checked if it returns other results than thoroughfare but you could give it a try.

Comment: Ok I tried that and the thorough is still blank until I move the lat and long far enough to find a valid address. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if it is then possible with the CoreLocation framework. I would try using the GoogleMaps API then. There you also have at least a few parameter to set. Especially I would look at the "location_type " parameter.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding